# Assing array value to input fields based on array indexes

Tags: php, arrays, loops

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title
        [intro] => Into
    )

[1] => Array
    (

        [title] => Title1
        [intro] => Into1
    )
```

This is array,how can i iterate over it and assign its value to some input field based on array index,like array index 0 will be assign to field 1,and index 1 to input field 2 and so on.

```
foreach($articles as $key=>$row)
 // if array index is 0
  <input type="text" name="test1" value="<?=$row['intro'];?>" />
// if array index is 0
  <input type="text" name="test2" value="<?=$row['intro'];?>" />
endforeach
```

Comment: I don't think the question is clear. Have a go expanding on your requirements ...

Comment: I need to assign array values to input fields base on array indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way

**Common framework way**

```
<? foreach($articles as $key => $row): ?>
    <input type="text" name="test<?=$key+1;?>" value="<?=$row['intro'];?>" />
<? endforeach; ?>
```

To prevent incompatibilities between servers, I suggest scrapping the PHP short tag `<?` with a full tag `<?php` as some servers do not have this enabled.

Basically, just add 1 to the key for every row. Key 0 will be `test1`, key 1 will be `test2` etc.

You are using a loop, so use a loop! You don't explicitly define every row when using a loop.

**Normal PHP way**

```
foreach($articles as $key => $row) {
    $inputName = "test".$key+1;
    echo "<input type='text' name='{$inputName}' value='{$row['intro']}'/>";
}
```